# I'm not sure what to do to have the expected output

Tags: c++

This is My Code

```
for(int y=1;y<=20;y++)
    {
          for(int z=1;z<=y;z++)
            {
                cout<<z;
                z++;
                cout<<z;
             }
        cout<<endl;
    }

return 0;
```

But the Output is this

```
12
12
1234
1234
123456
123456
12345678
12345678
12345678910
12345678910
123456789101112
123456789101112
1234567891011121314
1234567891011121314
12345678910111213141516
12345678910111213141516
123456789101112131415161718
123456789101112131415161718
1234567891011121314151617181920
1234567891011121314151617181920


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
```

Expected Output is this

```
12
1234
123456
12345678
12345678910
123456789101112
1234567891011121314
12345678910111213141516
123456789101112131415161618
1234567891011121314151616181920
```

Comment: BTW it is half pyramid it did not reflect on my post,

Comment: Use code blocks (triple backticks) to make text show exactly as pasted.

Comment: Your output looks fine to me, other than the fact that you are `cout`ing twice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In the future, please post your *full* code, including all that boilerplate stuff at the top, so we can easily run your code and reproduce your problem.  You want to make it as easy as possible for people to help.

Comment: Your outer loop counts from `1` to `20`, printing a line in every iteration.  It is not clear why you expected that to print 10 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can change the inner for loop the following way

```
for(int y=1;y<=20;y++)
{
      for( int z=1; z <= 2 * y; z++)
      {
          cout << z;
      }
      cout << endl;
}
```

If you want to output only 10 lines then change the condition in the outer loop

```
for(int y=1;y<=10;y++)
{
      for( int z=1; z <= 2 * y; z++)
      {
          cout << z;
      }
      cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: It will be more simple if increment `y` by 2 each loop, `y+=2` instead of `y++` and make z increment until y

Comment: Thank you that works bro, i forgot i can do that